# Word for whether a product is genuine or sham

Tags: single-word-requests

What word should be used to fill in the blank?

> We don't know whether a product is genuine or sham

means

> The product's  *_*_ is unverified.

Comment: *at present* would work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The word you are looking for is *authenticity*.

Answer (score 10):

“***Provenance***” is a great word for this use but maybe “*authenticity*” fits your specific example sentence a little better.

Answer (score 4):

since you mentioned the word already, you can try also [genuineness](http://www.wordnik.com/words/genuineness/)

> ```
> –noun
> The quality of being genuine; authenticity.
> ```

Comment: No doubt *genuineness* is a valid word but it's klunky compared to *authenticity*.

Comment: @AAT hmm. curious comment. And how would "genuiness" be MORE klunky [sic] than "authenticity". If there was a "klunky"[sic]-ness factor; what would the "klunky"[sic]-ness factor of "genuiness" vs. "authenticity"

Comment: well, it is not as euphonious for one thing, because of that double *n*. Is that enough of a reason?

Comment: @AAT in pronunciation I find three *n*s :)

Comment: @AAT good point :)

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple words which come to my mind which work, which vary depending on exactly what "the product" is:

- Authenticity - The product *is* what it says it *is*.  "Kansas City Barbeque"
- Efficacy - The product *does* what it says it *does*.  "This barbeque will make your mouth water."
- Veracity - The product is truthful, or product claims are truthful or have been verified.  "The hottest barbeque in town."

There is some overlap in authentic (to be genuine) and veracious (to be truthful).

Answer (score 2):

Another common word I would use in this sentence would be "claim".